# Yellowing/Browning from Mixing Ascorbic Acid with Calcium Carbonate and Glycerol

Tags: identification

I slowly get some yellowing / browning upon mixing ascorbic acid with calcium carbonate and glycerol and letting it sit at room temperature over time.

At first I thought it was ascorbic acid oxidating but it seems to happen even when kept in a full sealed container.

It's very humid where I'm at so I expect there is water in there too and suspect it accelerates the reaction as I get small amounts of a brown liquid in there as well.

Anyone knows what I'm dealing with?

Comment: What is the reason of mixing the acid and the carbonate in the first place ?

Comment: What is the purity (source) of the different compounds?

Comment: @Poutnik: The ascorbic acid has a dual effect, so it is also for CaCO3, the reason for the combination is that upon adding water there is a mild "foaming" effect, if it can be called so.

Comment: I would keep it as a binary mixture.

Comment: @Buck_Thorn The CaCO3 is fairly clean (>99%), so is the Ascorbic Acid (meets USP standards), and the Glycerine (>99.5%).